# Node & Heroku: Fails at start script, but works perfectly on my local machine

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am working on deploying Net Ninja's JWT authentication tutorial/project to heroku, but I am getting an error that I have not been able to overcome. This application works perfectly on my local computer. So far I've read through several stack overflow questions, but every fix for this issue that I've come across, I have already implemented.

Here are the heroku logs of my error.

```
2020-12-03T16:22:13.292858+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-12-03T16:22:13.292982+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the node-express-jwt-auth@1.0.0 start script.
2020-12-03T16:22:13.293125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-12-03T16:22:13.300898+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-03T16:22:13.301049+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-12-03T16:22:13.301127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-12-03T16_22_13_293Z-debug.log
2020-12-03T16:22:13.432936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-03T16:22:13.479796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-03T18:29:03.230278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=net-ninja-jwt-tutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=b693f181-6061-4704-ad14-08b71b6b0cb0 fwd="208.102.105.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-03T18:29:04.077018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=net-ninja-jwt-tutorial.herokuapp.com request_id=d363fc10-2e07-4e50-a024-c9f848b19c42 fwd="208.102.105.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "node-express-jwt-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.23",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/node-express-jwt-auth.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/node-express-jwt-auth/issues"
  },
  "engine":{
    "node":"12.x"
  }
}
```

My app.js file reads as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config()

// import cookie parser
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// import require auth
const {requireAuth, checkUser} = require('./middleware/authMiddleware')


// import authRoutes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
// below allows us to use JSON in our requests
app.use(express.json());
// allows us to use cookieParser as middleware
app.use(cookieParser());


// view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// database connection
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://david:Looping!@nodeauth.uj5ph.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex:true })
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(port)
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));


// routes
// 
app.get('*', checkUser);
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'));
app.get('/smoothies', requireAuth, (req, res) => res.render('smoothies'));

// allow us to import are authroutes into the app.js file.
app.use(authRoutes)

// cookies routes
// app.get('/set-cookies', (req, res) =>{
//   // res.setHeader('Set-Cookie','newUser=true')

//   // npm install cookie-parser
//   res.cookie("newUser", false);
//   res.cookie("isEmployee", true, {maxAge:1000*60*60*24, httpOnly:true});
//   res.send('you got the cookies!');
// });


// app.get('/read-cookies', (req, res) =>{
//   const cookies = req.cookies;
//   console.log(cookies)

//   res.json(cookies)
// });
```

Lastly, my procfile reads:

```
web:node app.js
```

If anyone were able to help me out with this, it would be a very big help.

On a side note, when my heroku logs read:

> 2020-12-03T16:22:13.301049+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log
> of this run can be found in: 2020-12-03T16:22:13.301127+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> /app/.npm/_logs/2020-12-03T16_22_13_293Z-debug.log

How would I go about accessing those error logs?

Edit: after running

```
$heroku logs --app net-ninja-jwt-tutorial
```

I disovered the following error:

```
2020-12-03T19:50:24.064213+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'
```

There's a lot more to the logs, but I /think/ this is the relevant issue. However, this confuses me, I have cookie-parser in my package.json file.

Comment: connect to your dyno using the [heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). Also note that you're showing the heroku error log well after the error start, which means we're not seeing the true error, just your redacted last few lines. Please show the actual full error.

Comment: Alright, after reading your comment I realized I needed to learn a bit more about how to access heroku error logs. I started on a tutorial on youtube (still going through it) but I found this error when running $heroku logs --app   net-ninja-jwt-tutorial.

"2020-12-03T19:50:24.064213+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'" . The thing is I have cookie parser in my package.json file, so I don't understand why I would have that error.

Comment: remember not to tell "me", but tell everyone by updating your post with previously missing information =) Also, I don't see cookie-parser listed in your `dependencies`, so from what you're showing: you don't.